# "countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:" Error

Tags: ios, xcode, semantics

I am trying to load a view controller where the accelerometer is moving an image view. the error in the title shows and the app crashes upon view loading.

```
- (void)collsionWithWalls {

    CGRect frame = self.Mover.frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.currentPoint.x;
    frame.origin.y = self.currentPoint.y;

    for (UIView *image in self.wall) {

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(frame, image.frame)) {

            // Compute collision angle
            CGPoint MoverCenter = CGPointMake(frame.origin.x + (frame.size.width / 2),
                                               frame.origin.y + (frame.size.height / 2));
            CGPoint imageCenter  = CGPointMake(image.frame.origin.x + (image.frame.size.width / 2),
                                               image.frame.origin.y + (image.frame.size.height / 2));
            CGFloat angleX = MoverCenter.x - imageCenter.x;
            CGFloat angleY = MoverCenter.y - imageCenter.y;

            if (abs(angleX) > abs(angleY)) {
                _currentPoint.x = self.previousPoint.x;
                self.MoverXVelocity = -(self.MoverXVelocity / 2.0);
            } else {
                _currentPoint.y = self.previousPoint.y;
                self.MoverYVelocity = -(self.MoverYVelocity / 2.0);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

The error shows on the line: 
    for (UIView *image in self.wall) {

Please help!

Comment: Show the complete error message. And what is the data type of `self.wall`?

Comment: The wall is an image which I want the mover to bounce off. The error shows: Collection expression type 'UIImageView *' may not respond to           'countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:'

Comment: Perhaps you want `for (UIImage *image in self.wall.animationImages)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for-in statement syntax:

```
for (UIView *image in self.wall) ...
```

should be read as "for each object, which we'll treat as a pointer to `UIView` and call `image`, in the collection `self.wall`, do…". From what you say, `self.wall` is not a collection. It's a `UIImageView`. That's the cause of the error. You're writing a statement which requires a collection, but you're not providing a collection.

So, why are you using a for loop here? There's nothing to loop over. Did you mean to use some other expression which would evaluate to a collection instead of `self.wall`?